# Using React Props with HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, jsx

Im trying to use props in React to display content from dynamic REST APIs. In the example below, Im trying to get a data from http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/  which display a random Chuck Norris Joke. Unfortunatly my app returns an error 500.

Any ideas on this??

```
import React from 'react';
import request from 'request';

const Api = (props) => {
  return <div>
            {request(props.api, (error, response, body) => {
                            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                                return body;
                            } else {
                                return error;
                            }
                        })
            }
        </div>;
}

const Default = (props) => {
    return ( <Api api="http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/"/> );
};
export default Default;
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should not do any sort of api call in the render method. The ideal way of doing this is:

```
class Api extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      data: null
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    request(this.props.api, (error, response, body) => {
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          this.setState({data: body})
      } else {
          return error;
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const content = this.state.data ? JSON.stringify(this.state.data) : <h3>Loading...</h3>

   return (
     <div class="content">
       {content}
     </div>
   )
 }
}
```

so what did we do:

We turned the stateless functional component into an ES6 class component that has data from the api as its state.

when it initializes data is null and once the component mounts it will make the api call and once the call completes and the results are returned it will update its own state which will cause the render method to be retriggered. Ideally you would parse the response and put it into the UI correctly but in this case we just turn the response into a string and render it into the DOM.

info on `componentDidMount`
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

info on `render()`
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render

Here is a working Pen: http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/xgqMae

i did have to use a different api library as the request.js you are using doesn't have an available cdn

Comment: Thanks for this. However I'm using PayPals react-engine and not ReactDOM to render. And I dont think componentDidMount works with react-engine. Any ideas?

Comment: The rendering agent doesn't matter a react component is a react component and should have the same prototypes/instance methods since you are still importing react from react